# How can you detect that a WikiVoyage page is out of date?

Tags: online-resources, tips-and-tricks, guidebooks

For my current trip to Cairns, one of the resources I used was the [Cairns WikiVoyage page](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cairns). The page is of a decent length, and has [guide article status](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:Guide_articles), so I figured it'd probably be largely ok to follow.

However, I [quickly discovered that the Get-In section was completely out of date](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40085/are-there-turn-up-and-board-shuttle-buses-from-cairns-airport-to-the-city-or), now fixed with help of Travel.SE! Several hotels were listed, but under names they no longer use, some under names not used for a long time (fixed where noticed). I then discovered from wandering about the city centre that there are a number of museums and gardens in the city, of which there were no mention (now fixed). I also spotted a few other problems, which I also resolved as best I could.

Luckily in this case, I had enough time and flexibility that it was all fine. On other trips though, it might be more of an issue.

So, what can I do to try to detect if a given apparently-OK-looking WikiVoyage page is fairly up-to-date, or if it's no longer likely to be current?

Comment: If some things are not  listed, that does not really mean the page is not current, only that it's not *exhaustive*. Not current would be if some things which are no longer there (or open) are still listed.

Comment: The get-in section was completely out of date, listing very old prices and bus operators no longer running. Likewise, hotels that changed names some time ago were there under old names, that sort of thing

Comment: Yes, sorry, I guss I didn't read the question carefully enough, I was just getting up.

Comment: And Wikivoyage fix has been fixed again, spelling error resolved ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since Wikivoyage is a wiki, every page has an associated history page, where you can see the date of each modification. With some effort, you could figure out when a particular piece of information was added. Of course, just because something was added long ago does not mean it's not current, however. For most things, especially businesses, you can generally do a Google search which would yield their homepage if they have one, or at least other pages referring to them, if it's still operating.

IMO you should always go with primary sources for such things anyway: things can and do change on very short notice, and even the best guide will get things wrong sometimes.

Comment: This raises an interesting idea for wikis in general: a feature to allow hovering with the mouse over any word or passage, and seeing a "tooltip" with information about when that word or passage was added or changed.